# Strange problem with orientation change when rotating device vertically(like somersault) in iPad

Tags: ipad, orientation

I am facing a rather strange problem when it comes to orientation change in iPad.  My App works absolutely fine when I rotate my device in the horizontal plane, from landscape to portrait or vice versa.  The problem arises when I rotate the device vertically (like a somersault).

The problem is that the frames of the views are getting distorted. I am calling my orientation change handling code from the `didRotateFromInterfaceorientation:fromInterfaceOrientation` method.  Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi Mr Hp
It is strange to see a issue that you got.Earlier when i test any app in ipad i used to check only in 360 degrees,but now on i think i should check even by somersaulting the device. I think you can approach Apple for your prob......

you are creating a new era in ipad testing , hats up to your idea of somersaulting the device and the thought is innovative.
any how check your code once again i think you missed some property settings either in code or plist.